# lateinit property vkUserRepository has not been initialized. Why?

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I try "kotlin - spring boot 2 - jpa".I just started to study spring-boot.
I have model, repository and app files. I`m use start.spring.io for starting.I’ve seen examples with web, but I don’t need a web.

I have error during compilation. Why ?
How can I fix this error?

```
2018-12-21 13:26:02.732  INFO 28188 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
2018-12-21 13:26:02.923  INFO 28188 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.LobCreatorBuilderImpl        : HHH000421: Disabling contextual LOB creation as hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation is true
2018-12-21 13:26:02.929  INFO 28188 --- [           main] org.hibernate.type.BasicTypeRegistry     : HHH000270: Type registration [java.util.UUID] overrides previous :         org.hibernate.type.UUIDBinaryType@396ef8b2
2018-12-21 13:26:03.335  INFO 28188 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2018-12-21 13:26:04.150  INFO 28188 --- [           main] r.k.v.VkUsersSkillApplicationKt          : Started VkUsersSkillApplicationKt in 4.348 seconds (JVM running for 4.905)
Exception in thread "main" kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property vkUserRepository has not been initialized
  at     ru.program.vkUsersSkill.VkUsersSkillApplicationKt.main(VkUsersSkillApplication.kt:17)
```

My program:

VkUser.kt

```
import javax.persistence.Column
import javax.persistence.Entity
import javax.persistence.Id
import javax.persistence.Table

@Entity
@Table (name = "vk_users")
data class VkUser(
    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    var userId: Long = 0L,

    @Column(name = "access_token")
    var accessToken: String = "",

    @Column(name = "alias")
    var alias: String = "",

    @Column(name = "login")
    var login: String = "",

    @Column(name = "password")
    var password: String = ""
)
```

VkUserRepository.kt

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository
import ru.program.vkUsersSkill.models.VkUser

@Repository
interface VkUserRepository: JpaRepository<VkUser, Long>
```

VkUsersSkillApplication.kt

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import ru.program.vkUsersSkill.repositories.VkUserRepository

@Autowired
lateinit var vkUserRepository: VkUserRepository

@SpringBootApplication
class VkUsersSkillApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  runApplication<VkUsersSkillApplication>(*args)
  vkUserRepository.findAll()
}
```

application.properties

```
spring.jpa.database-platform =org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/vkadmin
spring.datasource.username=vkadmin
spring.datasource.password=pass 
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

Comment: Can you post application.properties?

Comment: @Jonathan Johx , added properties file.

Comment: Add on VkUsersSkillApplication class header @EntityScan(basePackages = {"run.program.xxxxx.entities" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"ru.program.xxxxx.repositories"}) ... Change your packages respectively

Comment: @Jonathan Johx , this is not work ((( Error not change. screen here https://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2018/12/3850e452ff28762f2f708a9f09b69d36.png

Comment: You can't call in application class some repository, why? Because you are starting the application and it's not loaded your application yet, so remove that variables and logic, if you want to load data or getting from repositories you need to implement some class after the application runs...

Comment: @Jonathan Johx, Can you show me something for example ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185655/discussion-between-jonathan-johx-and-adrenal1ne).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create start class-bean

```
@Component
class StartHere {
@Autowired
lateinit var vkUserRepository: VkUserRepository
fun runHere() {
    var users = vkUserRepository.findAll()
    println(users)
}

//TODO all other program code here
}
```

Then in MAIN function we get 'application context' and run our bean-starter

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import ru.program.vkUsersSkill.init.StartHere

@SpringBootApplication
class VkUsersSkillApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
val context = runApplication<VkUsersSkillApplication>(*args)
val start = context.getBean(StartHere::class.java)
start.runHere()
}
```

All is done.
Thanks to @Jonathan Johx.